# Give wrong GPS coordinates at first time

Tags: iphone, gps

to all  i want to know why location manager in iphone gives wrong coordinate at first time when run application.Due to this my distance is come 100 meter at start of application and my average speed is also effected due to this

Comment: This has been happening to me too. If i close it and reopen the app it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each location you receive will have a horizontal accuracy.  If the accuracy is above some threshold, say 10 meters, then disregard it.  It will take longer to get an accurate read.  A negative accuracy means unknown and should also be discarded.

You could also keep your current logic, but reset all data the first time the accuracy is below your threshold.  You will still be disregarding inaccurate data, but you can give the user some initial feedback the way map programs do.

Which approach to use depends on your application.